# unable to tap the correct element on Iphone X simulator using calabash-cucumber 0.21.1

Tags: ruby, calabash, calabash-ios, iphone-x

I have updated my xcode to 9 and calabash-cucumber to 0.21.1 and runloop to 2.6.1. I am trying to run my tests on IPhoneX simulator to tap on a particular element but its tapping on somewhere on the screen. It worked fine until iPhone 7. Even the irb taps on different location. Is it the problem with the scale of the device or any gem issue? Please help.

Comment: Please provide some additional information related to your question. It could be a sample of code, that taps some area, cucumber logs or even a screencast where we can see what's going wrong.

Comment: i am trying to use this method

def fill_username_data(username)
    fill USERNAME_FIELD, username.to_s, true
  end

So its just a simple tap and fill the username data in username field.